# ¿Como puedo aplicar onBackPressed en un Fragment?

Tags: java, android-studio

estoy creando una aplicación móvil, el cual estoy empezando con el Front-end y aque tengo creado el Drawer Navigation, después de seleccionar un opción del menú se dirige a un `Fragment` el cual tengo un `Toolbar` con un titulo y un icono o vector de retroceso o atrás, lo que quiero es que al dar clic al icono me redirija hacia atrás o me mande hacia el menú principal.

**Código de mi fragmento**

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="114dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Contingencia" />

<include
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/toolbar_volcan">
</include>
```

**Código de toolbar**

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_volcan"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="#30475E"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/retroceso"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_retroceder">

    </ImageView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="19dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:text="@string/titulo_volcan"/>

</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Puedes revisar la respuesta de [mrengineer13](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26656285/15245917) donde esta mejor explicado.

En el metodo onCreateView del fragment podrias hacer lo siguiente:

```
@Nullable
@org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull @NotNull LayoutInflater inflater, 
@Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //Inflamos la vista del fragment
    View view  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment_layout, container, false);

    //Encontramos el toolbar
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_volcan);
    //Agregamos el icono del boton de retroceso al toolbar
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.my_icon);
    //Agregamos lo que queremos que haga el boton al darle click
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Accedemos al OnbackPressed del activity
            getActivity().onBackPressed();
        }
    });
    //Retornamos la vista 
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Considera agregar una explicación a tus respuestas. Pegar un código solamente no es una respuesta de calidad. Puede resultar obvio para ti pero tal vez no sea tan obvio para otras personas.